# how to assign a dynamic parameter in an array in the computed method and mapState

Tags: vue.js, vuex, computed-properties, mapstatetoprops

hello here is my computed method :

```js
computed:
    mapState({
    aftermovie: (state) => state.festival.aftermovies[id]
  }),
    id: {
      set() { return this.$route.params.id}
    },
```

if i put state.festival.aftermovies [0] it works but if i try to get id in url, id is undefined, can you help me please

Comment: this should work `state.festival.aftermovies[this.$route.params.id]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you very much yes indeed we can not access **this** in **mapState** here is the functional solution:

```js
data() {
    return {
    // -1 because the aftermovie index is 1 and the index in the array starts at 0
      id: this.$route.params.id - 1
    }
  },
  computed:
    mapState({
      aftermovies: (state) => state.festival.aftermovies
    }),
```

and finally to access the data

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div>
        {{ aftermovies[this.id].id }}
        {{ aftermovies[this.id].name }}
        {{ aftermovies[this.id].video }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you can't access `this` or other computed property in `mapState`, try the following:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    aftermovies: (state) => state.festival.aftermovies
  }),
  id() {
    return this.$route.params.id
  },
  aftermovie() {
    return this.aftermovies[this.id]
  }
}
```

Comment: nope it does not work, it returns me the answer: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined